# preg_match not accepting $this

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Am I being stupid or does `preg_match()` not accept global class variables?

```
class test{
    private$username,$usernameValidation;
    public function __construct($username){
        $this->username=$username;
        $this->usernameValidation="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,8}$/";
    }
    public function validate(){
       if(!preg_match($this->usernameValidation,$this->username)){
           //failed;
       }
    }
}
```

Every time I compile a function like this, it seems to tell me the the expression is empty.
Seems to work as `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,8}$/",$this->username);`.

Comment: How are you creating instance of your class?

Comment: @anubhava I can update it if you'd like?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually calling `validate()`? I tested your code, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @EdCottrell yea! I would've thought it would have worked also! No idea, just doesn't like me :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try keeping regex assignment at class level:

```
class test {
    const UsernameValidation = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,8}$/';
    private $username;

    public function __construct($username){
        $this->username=$username;
    }
    public function validate(){
       if(!preg_match(UsernameValidation, $this->username)) {
           //failed;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`{,8}` is not a valid repetition, I guess you want: `{0,8}` or `{8,}`

Comment: No, sorry it's still apparently an empty expression. Thank for your help though, I missed that error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between `private` and `$username` or you will get a syntax error. This code works:

```
class test{
    private $username,$usernameValidation;
    public function __construct($username){
        $this->username=$username;
        $this->usernameValidation="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,8}$/";
    }
    public function validate(){
        if(!preg_match($this->usernameValidation,$this->username)){
            echo 'failed';
        }
        else {
            echo 'matched';
        }
    }
}

$foo = new test('abcdefg');
$foo->validate();
```

[**Demo Link**](http://ideone.com/oXKiz3)

Comment: Shouldn't need a space. I'll try it but I'm sure a space isn't required.

Comment: To clarify, it threw a syntax error on the site I used for the above demo. I can't access a computer with a PHP interpreter installed right now, other than via the web, so that may be a glitch.

Comment: I've always done it and never had a problem in the past. Thanks for your help by the way. Bit of a silly question; I just can't work it out! normally for javascript you need a space after variable declaration but never had a problem with PHP because I think it's to do with the `$` dollar symbol.